# Write XML file from graphic field and read

Tags: xml, delphi, dataset

I need some help here...
I have a Paradox Table in delphi 7 with a graphic field. With this: http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=772 I can make a XML file like biolife.xml from delphi's demos but without the graphic field. I added:
 `ftGraphic: Result  := '"bin.hex" SUBTYPE="Graphic"';` 
 at the code, but nothing... The XML file ending:

`Im=" /></ROWDATA></DATAPACKET>`
After Im=" should be the image code, but it's empty, and didn't close the quotes either. For the graphic field I use:

```
image1.Picture:= nil;
panel1.PaintTo(image1.Canvas.Handle,0,0);
table1.edit;
table1.FieldByName('Im').Assign(image1.Picture.Bitmap);    
table1.Post;
```

What I want is to create an XML file like "biolife.xml" from delphi. So any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you link writes plain XML files, not files like `Biolife.xml`. Graphics can't be stored in a plain XML file (they have to be encoded when written, and decoded when read). The post (written by Mike Skolnik) doesn't use a graphic field because graphics are binary data and not suitable for standard XML (and can't be properly written or read by storing in a string and then being written to a `TFileStream`.)

`Biolife.xml` is not a graphics file. It's a `TClientDataSet` (CDS for short), stored in XML format. It has an XML extension, but it's far from a simple XML file like the article you link is creating.

(If this is TLDR, just skip to the paragraph further down marked **Short Answer**.)

[`TClientDataSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet) is an in-memory dataset that can be persisted (saved) to a file, in either binary or XML format. In other words, it's a special type of database. (See further down in my answer for more info.)

Paradox has limits on the types of graphics it can store and directly use in a `TGraphicField`, but I don't remember what they are off-hand. (Paradox is accessed via the Borland Database Engine, or BDE, and it has been deprecated for more than a decade now, and I haven't used it since Delphi 1 in the mid-1990s.) You can see the possible types that `TGraphicField` can store in the Delphi 7 help file for the `TGraphicField.SetFieldType` method; the only actual image file it seems to accept is `ftGraphic`, which is a bitmap.

The `FishFacts` demo in Delphi 7 shows how to work with Paradox graphics, as it uses a Paradox database for its storage mechanism IIRC. It's located in the `C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Demos\DB\FishFacts` folder in the default installation on Windows XP. There's also a `BioLife.cds` (`.cds` is the binary format `TClientDataSet` storage default extension) in the `C:\Program Files\Borland Shared\Data` directory.

In other words, don't confuse the fact that the `Biolife.xml` file has an `.XML` extension fool you. It's a special format file that's pretty much useless except when being accessed through a `TClientDataSet`. (Open it in a text editor like Notepad; a regular XML file is pretty clearly structured and readable, while a CDS XML file isn't as neat and tidy.

There were some articles on the Borland Developer site about using `TClientDataSet` by Cary Jensen, who wrote several books and articles on database programming in Delphi. He wrote an excellent series starting with [`A ClientDataSet in Every Database Application`](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28876) that should get you started, if you're wanting to use a `TClientDataSet` like `Biolife.xml`.

**Short answer**: If you want to store a graphic in a Paradox `TGraphicField`, store an actual graphic image in a supported format to that field, or create an actual graphic file and store it with `LoadFromStream` or `LoadFromFile`. It has to be an actual graphic file though (like a bitmap); it can't just be anything you want to put in the field.

An example of something that would work based on the code you posted:

```
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  BmpField: TGraphicField;
begin
  BmpField := table1.FieldByName('Im') as TGraphicField;
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.Width := Panel1.Width;
    Bitmap.Height := Panel1.Height;
    Panel1.PaintTo(Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0);
    table1.Edit;
    BmpField.Assign(Bitmap);
    table1.Post;
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you want to use a `TClientDataSet` like `Biolife.xml` to store your data, here's how to get started.

You can find `TClientDataSet` on the Component Palette in the `Data Access` tab in Delphi 7. It acts just like any other `TDataSet`, which means you can define persistent fields, insert/delete/edit data, filter, create indexes, and so forth.

The basics of using it are simple: Just drop it on the form, and assign a filename. Right-click it, and choose `Fields Editor...` from the pop-up menu. Right-click the `Fields Editor` when it appears, and choose `New Field`. Define the field you want to store, along with its type, just like you would any other dataset. Repeat until you've added all of the fields you want in your CDS. Then close the `Field Editor`, and right-click the `TClientDataSet` again; there will be a `Create Dataset` option that wasn't there before. Choose it, and you'll have your new dataset.

Now you can use it as normal: create indexes, insert, edit, and delete records (rows), search (using `Locate`), filter, and so forth. It can be connected (through a `TDataSource`) to any data aware controls like `TDBGrid`, just like any other dataset. You can also create graphic and memo fields, which is extremely difficult to do in "normal" XML; the CDS takes care of encoding and decoding everything for you.

Comment: Thank you for answer.(a little late but last night my net went off). Now I can see clearly what do you mean. Simply saving a dataset to file give me the format that i wanted an i can reload it and work with the data. About the paradox tables... well... I will install Firebird, but i don't know yet how's working... Thanks once again for quick answer.